# SQL - Get the antepenultimate (before previous group/phase)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table and I'd like to get the antepenultimate or the value before the previous value.

I already have `group`, `value` and `prev_value`, `dateint`... I'm trying to derive `prev_prev_value`

```
 grp  value  prev_value    prev_prev_value     dateint
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 1       x       null         null               20200101
 1       x       null         null               20200102
 2       y        x           null               20200103
 2       y        x           null               20200104
 2       y        x           null               20200105
 3       z        y             x                20200106
 3       z        y             x                20200107
 3       z        y             x                20200108
 4       a        z             y                20200109
```

This is the table with test data (as a CTE)

```
with test as (
    select  1  as grp,     'x' as value ,      null as prev_value , 20200101 as dateint
    union
    select  1  as grp,     'x' as value ,      null as prev_value , 20200102 as dateint
    union
    select  2  as grp,     'y' as value ,      'x' as prev_value  , 20200103 as dateint
    union
    select  2  as grp,     'y' as value ,      'x' as prev_value  , 20200104 as dateint
    union
    select  2  as grp,     'y' as value ,      'x' as prev_value ,  20200105 as dateint
    union
    select  3  as grp,     'z' as value ,      'y' as prev_value ,  20200106 as dateint
    union
    select  3  as grp,     'z' as value ,      'y' as prev_value ,  20200107 as dateint
    union
    select  3  as grp,     'z' as value ,      'y' as prev_value ,  20200108 as dateint
    union
    select  4  as grp,     'a' as value ,      'z' as prev_value ,  20200109 as dateint

)
```

Any ideas on how to derive `prev_prev_value` I'd like to use window functions and avoid joins.

I've tried `LAG` but I have not been successful.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want to 'derive' prev_prev_value but the code you share isn't deriving anything, its just hard coded to produce the table you provided (minus the extra column). Why not just add the column you want in the same fashion?

Comment: the hard-coded code is for you to use it as a starting point (sample) and write a query on top of it, as specified in the stackoverflow guidelines, I should've been more clear

Comment: I will not mark the solution as answered yet @SimonN if you happen to find a different one or better than that one I will consider it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that a nested `FIRST(LAG..` did the job:

The logic behind that was to get the previous (lag) `prev_value` and get the FIRST value of that group

```
select grp,
       value,
       prev_value,
       FIRST(LAG(prev_value) over (order by dateint)) over (partition by grp order by dateint) as prev_prev_value,
       dateint
from test order by dateint
```

Comment: Glad you've found a solution, but lag is a window function which you said you didn't want.

Comment: in fact I wanted to use a window function, in my post I said that I was avoiding a join and that I had been trying with LAG ...I found  FIRST and voila, it all made sense, sorry if my post was not that clear , will edit it so that other can find it more clear

Comment: Ah, okay, yes I had misunderstood your final sentence, much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a window frame:

```
select t.*,
       LAST_VALUE(prev_value) OVER (ORDER BY dateint 
                                    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                   ) as prev_prev_value
from test t
order by dateint ;
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't believe this returns the expected `prev_prev_value` it returns something like
[NULL, NULL, NULL, x, ...] instead of [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, x,...] did i miss something?